# Unable to copy multiline text file to a buffer

Tags: c, windows, winapi, text-files

I am trying to copy a text file to a buffer in order to send it over the socket. As soon as the text file does not have any newlines (or \n), the file is successfully copied into  buffer. But, whenever there are multiple lines in a text file, I get an error, *"Unable to copy file into buffer"*.

Below is the code snippet:

```
//=====================Sending a File at Socket=========================
   FILE *fp = fopen("File.txt", "r+");
   char file_buffer[1000];

   fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
   size_t file_size = ftell(fp); //calculating File Size

   fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
   int bytes_read=0;
   if((bytes_read=fread(file_buffer, 1, file_size, fp))<=0)
     {
       MessageBox( NULL,
               "Unable to copy file into buffer",
               "Error!",
               MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | 
               MB_OK);
      exit(1);
     }
     MessageBox( NULL,
             file_buffer,
            "File copied in Buffer",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | 
            MB_OK);
```

**NOTE:** *The code works perfectly fine if the text file contains no new lines.*

Comment: note for efficiency, the `1` should be third argument to `fread()`, not second. Would you rather read file_size 1-byte elements, or one file_size-sized item?

Comment: @Rohan : I edited my code for file_size

Comment: What does `errno` or `ferror()` or `GetLastError()` tell you?

Comment: @alk : If I am not worng in reading the error, errno retunrs 0

Comment: try opening the file in binary mode `FILE *fp = fopen("File.txt", "r+b");`

Comment: You do yourself a favour adding the value of `errno` and the result of `ferror()` to the error message you are giving if `fread()` returns `0`.

Comment: OT: `fread()` returns a `size_t`, which `unsigned`  per defintion, so there is no need to test for `<0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

Open the file with the "rb+" mode instead of "r+",

---

**Long answer**

You are opening the file with the "r+" mode. With that mode all "\r\n" sequences (that is Windows line endings") are translated into "\n" (that is Unix line endings).

But the file size returned by ftell will give you the real file size without translation.

**Example**

Content of File.txt

```
12\r\n34
```

The size of this file is 6 bytes

Content of file_buffer after fread with "r+" mode :

```
12\n34
```

In that case the return value of fread will be 5.

Content of file_buffer after fread with "rb+" mode :

```
12\r\n34
```

In that case the return value of fread will be 6. You can check this with the debugger. Read the documentation of [fopen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx).

**More problems in your code**

Your call to MessageBox will display the file contents possibly followed by garbage because you are not putting a zero terminator.

Add this to your program after the call to [fread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt0etdcs.aspx)

```
file_buffer[bytes_read] = 0 ;
```

---

Testing an error condition with fread by testing if its return value is < 0 is not correct; anyway the return value type of fread is size_t (which is unsigned) and not int, write `size_t bytes_read=0;` instead of `int bytes_read=0;`

Excerpt from the [fread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt0etdcs.aspx) documentation:

> fread returns the number of full items actually read, which may be
>   less than count if an error occurs or if the end of the file is
>   encountered before reaching count. Use the feof or ferror function to
>   distinguish a read error from an end-of-file condition. If size or
>   count is 0, fread returns 0 and the buffer contents are unchanged. If
>   stream or buffer is a null pointer, fread invokes the invalid
>   parameter handler, as described in Parameter Validation. If execution
>   is allowed to continue, this function sets errno to EINVAL and returns
>   0.

Comment: @alk: actually we don't know if it return 0 or a something < 0. But you are right it doesn't explain it really.

Comment: We surely know it's `0`. Please see my comment to the OP on what `fread()` returns.

Comment: @alk: ok, I know what you mean.